# How can I set the parity bits when using screen to access a serial port

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, serial-port

I typically use **screen**(1) to open a serial port with the command:

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB2 115200
```

I've tried setting parenb (and a number of other things) using the following command:

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB2 115200,cs8,parenb,-parodd,-cstopb
```

However, the system doesn't seem to respect this. Here are the settings as reported by **stty** while I'm in **screen** with the above command:

```
$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB2 -a
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^H; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 100; time = 2;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Note the `-parenb` despite the fact that I enabled it at the command line.

If I make the change manually to ttyUSB2 it isn't respected after (nor while) running **screen**.

Set parenb:

```
$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB2 parenb
```

Check its value:

```
$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB2 -a
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^H; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 100; time = 2;
parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

You can see parenb is set properly.

Run **screen**:

```
$ sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB2 115200,cs8,parenb,-parodd,-cstopb
```

Check parenb again:

```
$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB2 -a
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^H; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 100; time = 2;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Oops, it's back to being `-parenb`.

What's going on?

How would I modify this command to use even parity (specifically 8e1 instead of the default 8n1)?

OS is Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS with the latest HWE.

Comment: Try creating another shell in the same window, while the original shell is still running, to run **stty**:  `exec ! stty parenb -parodd`.  This is derived from an example (for baud rate) in the **man** page.

Comment: see [Screen command set baud rate for terminal transmission - nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-apple-osx-bsd-screen-set-baud-rate/) for some syntax help, but no clue where it comes from: `screen /dev/ttySX baud_rate,cs8|cs7,ixon|-ixon,ixoff|-ixoff,istrip|-istrip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, it looks as if `screen` doesn't support setting those flags. The alternative would be to run `stty` to set the flags while screen is connected to the port, as you've done. Alternately, you could run [kermit](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/) or another terminal emulator program inside a conventional screen command-line session, instead of having screen connect directly to the serial port.

The `screen` source code is at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git. It looks like the file of interest is [tty.sh](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/tty.sh). This is shell script which runs during the build process to produce "tty.c". tty.c contains the code for accessing serial ports.

The function `SttyMode()` appears to be what parses the tty options and sets the tty mode. It appears to me that it handles a small, fixed set of options. "parenb" and "parodd" aren't among them.

It looks like it'd be straightforward for a developer experienced with C to add support for these options, if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 9):

Try `sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB2 115200,cs8,parenb,-parodd,-cstopb`

From [the man page for `stty`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stty):

- csN - set character size to N bits, N in [5..8]
- [-]parenb - generate parity bit in output and expect parity bit in input
- [-]parodd - set odd parity (even with '-')
- [-]cstopb - use two stop bits per character (one with '-')

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I updated my question with many more details.